# How to send parameter ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

how to send a parameter(parameter called kanwil) to controller in ajax? i try something like this to get value from the controller, but it doesn't work

```
function getBranchWil() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/CreateAccount/getBranchWil")',
                data: "{kanwil : '02'}",
                success: function (data) {
                    var s = '<option value="-1">--- Wilayah ---</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        s += '<option value="' + data[i].Kanwil + '">' + data[i].Kanwil + ' - ' + data[i].Kanwil_Name + '</option>';
                    }
                    $("#BranchDropdown").html(s);
                }
            });
        }
```

the controller

```
public ActionResult getBranchWil(string kanwil)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();


            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM \"MST_BRANCH_TAB\" WHERE \"Bank_Flag\"=@Bank_Flag AND \"Kanwil\" =@kanwil  ORDER BY \"Branch\" asc ";


                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bank_Flag", "KONVEN");

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(item: new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = reader["Branch_Name"].ToString(),
                        Value = reader["Branch"].ToString()
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            return Json(items.Select(x => new
            {
                Branch = x.Value,
                Branch_Name = x.Text
            }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

how to send the parameter? for example the value of kanwil is '02', i want to achieve a list from the controller with parameter i send

Comment: Don't send that data object as a string. Just leave it as `{kanwil : '02'}`. jQuery will automatically convert that to the proper string format for you. It would be `kanwil=02` if you were to do it as a string, but better to leave it for jQuery to do that conversion for you.

Comment: which part should i change? i can't delete string type in controller, controller need type data

Comment: Just remove the quotes surrounding the `{kanwil : '02'}` in your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: ooh i see, it's worked thank you